# how to optimize this particular jquery code?

Tags: jquery, optimization

can any  one will know how to reduce the code duplication    and optimization of this j query code. which contain same functionality on particular click event on different block.

```
 $('#lr-btn').on('click',function(){
            $('.lr-list').toggle();
        });
        $('#lt-btn').on('click',function(){
            $('.lt-list').toggle();
        });
        $('.lr-list ul li').on('click',function(){
            var a  =  $(this).find('span').html();
            $('.lr-list ul  input[type=radio]').removeAttr('checked');
            $(this).find('input[name=leave_reason]').prop('checked', 'checked');
            if(a == 'Other') {
                $('.leave-reason').show();
            }else{
                $('.leave-reason').hide();
            }
            $('.lr-list').hide();
            $('#lr-btn').html(a);
        });

        $('.lt-list ul li').on('click',function(){
            var a  =  $(this).find('span').html();
            $('.lt-list ul  input[type=radio]').removeAttr('checked');
            $(this).find('input[name=leave_type]').prop('checked', 'checked');
            $('.lt-list').hide();
            $('#lt-btn').html(a);
        });
```

Comment: why have you write more then one `$('.lr-list ul li').on('click')`

Comment: both are different list and different hidden input value

Comment: It can be done with one `$('.lr-list ul li').on('click')`.

Comment: `$('#lt-btn, #lr-btn').on('click', function() {
    $('.' + this.id).toggle();
});`

Comment: Can you show your HTML?

Comment: Wouldn't this be question do better over on [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Answer (score 0):

I can't test it to be sure everything works as intended without your HTMl but this should get what you are looking for. [The Ternary Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) can greatly reduce your code but be careful as it can also make your code harder to understand in some cases:

```
 $('.btns').on('click', function() { // give both buttons class="btns" and give them data-target=".lr-list" and data-target=".lt-list" respectively
     $($(this).data('target')).toggle();
 });
 $('.lr-list ul li, .lt-list ul li').on('click', function() {
   var $this=$(this);
   var a = $this.find('span').html();
   $this.closest('ul').find('input[type="radio"]').removeAttr('checked');
   var type= $this.closest('.lr-list').length > 0 ? 'lr' : 'lt';
   var inputName= type == 'lr' ? 'leave_reason' : 'leave_type';
   $this.find('input[name="'+inputName+'"]').prop('checked', 'checked');
   type=='lr' && a == 'Other' ? $('.leave-reason').show() : $('.leave-reason').hide(); 
   $('.'+type+'-list').hide();
   $('#'+type+'-btn').html(a);
});
```